# When to use what inverse trig?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

When do I use $\arcsin$ and when do I need to include all of the outcomes? My gut feeling is if you have an equation like $\sin(x)=0$, then $x=0,\pi,2\pi...$ whilst if you are using it in integration and any other situation you use $\arcsin$.
Is this correct if either way why?? thanks

Comment: elaborate a little more? give an example.

Comment: What do you mean by "using it in integration" and how is it different?

Comment: If were for example using trig substitution e.g. x=sin(u) and in the final answer we got a u by itself we would put u=acrsin(x) in its place would we not? what other situations does this occur in?

Comment: Likewise sometimes we use sin=(+/-)(1-cos^2)^0.5 and others just  sin=(1-cos^2)^0.5 are there any rules of when we use the one-to-one functions and many-to-one (as i think they are called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, arcsin(x) is defined as the number y in the range $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ with the property $sin(y) = x$. With this restriction,
the inverse of sin(x) is well-defined. Solving the equation sin(x) = 0 is
something else, here you do not restrict the range of the possible values,
and you get infinite many solutions.

If arcsin(x) occurs in an integral, the definition I described 
should be meant.

Comment: In general do we use the many values version only when solving equations, otherwise we use acrsin etc??

Comment: Yes, I would say so.